# Plugin vim-signature: How to change mark column character color?

Tags: mark, color

Currently mark character is bright red as in below screenshot. 
How to change it?

[image]

Comment: This is not a default behavior, I guess you are using a plugin to show the mark in the gutter. You should 1) indicate which plugin you use 2) ask your question on the plugin issue tracker.

Comment: Try following the steps in [How do I debug my vimrc file?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/51).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the vim-signature plugin uses the `SignatureMarkText` highlighting group for its mark signs.

It's better to set the colour of this in your `vimrc` rather than editing the plugin's code (which could cause problems if/when you want to update the plugin).

Add the following line to your `vimrc` file:

```
highlight SignatureMarkText guifg=White ctermfg=White
```

(You can also run this command from command-line mode to apply the change without restarting Vim.)

Note that the plugin uses the same mechanism for setting the colour, the `CheckAndSetHL()` function (for which you altered the parameters in your answer) builds essentially the same command as the above.

Answer (score 2):

Mark column is added by plugin: `vim-signature`.

Need to edit: `$HOME/.vim/bundle/vim-signature/autoload/signature/utils.vim`

Change 'SignatureMarkText' color.

Need to exit vim to see the change.

[image]